# How to create component with new data and params or set new methods in VUE?

Tags: vue.js, vue-component

How to create component with new data and params or set new methods in VUE?
Why this dont work? How to set new data itemList?

```html
    <dropdown-sort-list id="dropdown-sort-list"></dropdown-sort-list>

    <script>
        let dropdown = Vue.component('dropdown-sort-list', {

            data: function () {
                return {
                    itemList: [{name: 1111111111}],
                }
            },
            template: `
                            <a class="dropdown-item dot" href="#" v-bind:key="item.name" v-for="(item, index) in itemList">{{item.name}}</a>
                  `
        });

        var dropdownEx = new dropdown({
            el: "#dropdown-sort-list",
            data: {
                itemList: [{name: 2222222222}],
            },
        });

    </script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Your `dropdown-sort-list` is rendering multiple root nodes, which is illegal in Vue.js. You should only render 1 root node per component, adding a wrapper for your component should make it work:

```html
<div>
  <a class="dropdown-item dot" href="#" v-bind:key="item.name" v-for="(item, index) in itemList">{{item.name}}</a>
</div>
```

Note: Functional Components do not have this limitation.